# Lightning Component -- Calling APEX function

Tags: aura

First off...I am new to SF development and only dabble in javascript.  My first "project" was creating an APEX class which calls an external web service (which i created and hosted on AWS). This class returns a single string value:

```
public class myUtils {

   @AuraEnabled
   public static string retValue(){
     String value;
     String payLoad = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzZXJ2ZXIiOiJodHRwczovL2RlbW8udHNlcnZlcnRydXN0LnRhYmxlYXUuY29tL3RydXN0ZWQvIiwidX';
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setEndpoint('https://myServerOnAWS/endpoint/doSomething/');
     req.setMethod('POST');
     req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');

     req.setBody(payLoad);

     Http http = new Http();
     HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

     String htmlRsp = res.getBody().replace('\'','\\\'');

     string regex = '&quot;(.*)&quot;';
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
     Matcher m = p.matcher(htmlRsp);

     if(m.find()){
       value = m.group(1);
     }

        return(value);

    }
}
```

Successfully tested this using a simple VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="myUtils">
    <apex:outputText value="{!retValue}" />
</apex:page>
```

Now, **I am struggling to understand the best way to call this apex class in lightning** which would return this string value. I created an Aura component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <lightning:input aura:id="url" label="url" name="url" placeholder="url" type="url"/><br/>
    <lightning:button label="Send Request" onclick="{!c.thirdpartyClientCall}"/>
</aura:component>
```

And controller:

```
({ 

    thirdpartyClientCaller : function(cmp, event, helper) { 
        var action = cmp.get("c.retValue"); 

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) { 
            var state = response.getState(); 
            if (state === "SUCCESS") { 
                console.log("SUCCESS");
            } 
            else { 
                console.log("FAILED");
            } 
        }); 

        $A.response(action); 
        } 
    })
```

When i inspect the page, i see nothing in the console.  Any thoughts on what i'm missing?

Comment: `thirdpartyClientCall` and `thirdpartyClientCaller`. Check the spelling in aura component

Comment: Second @RohitMourya suggestion

Comment: @BryanAnderson Not sure, can you suggest it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have found 4 issues.

1. your lightning component doesn't have Apex controller you have to add controller like below

   ```
   aura:component controller="myUtils" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
   ```
2. check spelling: `thirdpartyClientCall` and `thirdpartyClientCaller`
3. check user profile Access for `myUtils` apex class.
4. and replace `$A.response(action);` in your js controller  with `$A.enqueueAction(action);`

Comment: good catch. I missed the controller part. +1

Comment: Wow...thank you for the quick feedback!  I have fixed/validated the three issues you identified and redeployed.  Currently, when i click the "Send Request" button, nothing happens.  When i inspect the page, there's simply nothing being returned.  I would expect to see something in the console b/c of the controller code. Thoughts?

Comment: updated with 4th issue please consider and let me know

Comment: Yes! Now i'm getting "Success".  Last question, how do I return the actual value returned from the apex class?

Comment: `response.getReturnValue()`  gives Apex method return value, i would recommend go through https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm. if your issue resolve please upvote my solution for help to others

Comment: Many thanks @sdandamud1 and all others...very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The function call in the aura component doesn't matches with the controller function name.
`thirdpartyClientCall` and `thirdpartyClientCaller`

And rightly added by @sdandamud1, the controller is not mentioned in Aura Component.